# What can I do about network traffic with uknown source and destination?

Tags: ipv4

I am getting more than 60% of this traffic in my network.

```
Source Ethernet Address (6 bytes)                 00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION)
Destination Ethernet Address (6 bytes)            00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION)

Data (43 bytes)
```

What can I do to determine where this traffic is coming from?

How can I get rid of this traffic once the source is found?

Comment: How did verify this is happening? PCAP on a switch port? Was it monitor port or normal port? What does the data contain? If you have full PCAP it would be useful.

Comment: consider adding a mac acl that denies those adresses...

Comment: Something isn't right here and we would need more information.  Please consider editing your question.

Comment: What protocol is being encapsulated? IPv4?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

This could be a misconfigured VM or multiple misonfigured VMs.  That is where I saw the all zeroes originating before myself.

Getting rid of the traffic is easy.  In an enterprise class switch, you should be able to add a static *DROP* entry to the MAC address table.  This would cause the switch to drop this traffic at L2.

As for identifying the source, I wouldn't worry about that as they VMs probably are not functioning properly in any case.  Blocking them should be sufficient, and the loss of all connectivity should point out the source (or create a support call) if it is legitimate.

Comment: Blocking only hides the problems. A broken device is still spewing packets. If this is a misconfigured VM, it needs to be found and the path that led to it's creation FIXED.

Comment: @RickyBeam, generally I would agree with this stance, but since most enterprise switches will drop this in hardware, there is no performance loss.  I equate this to DHCP snooping in that it is just dropping the problematic traffic rather than letting it affect other devices on the network.  If you have the time/ability to track it down later, absolutely you should do so (same with rogue DHCP), but it isn't a service impacting problem at that point and depending on the situation, it moves much further down the priority list.

Comment: I wouldn't call 2960S's an enterprise switch, but it most certainly will ***NOT*** drop those; it won't put all-zero in the cam, thus has no dst for all-zero *bam* unicast flood.  I hunt down and destroy VMs that do that, and then "have words" with the creator of said VM -- everyone in my office (all 8) know what they're doing to make those. (it's one of many stupid things our software can do)

Comment: @RickyBeam, not sure where the 2960S switches come from, but they are definitely enterprise switches (CLI, SNMP, syslog, STP, detailed port stats, etc), unless you are only counting switches that can do L3.  As for your assertion, I don't have access to a 2960S currently, but a 2950 (two gens back) will accept an all-zero drop statement and drop traffic, I can't imagine a 2960S wouldn't be able to do the same (although I wouldn't be overly surprised to find out it couldn't for some odd reason).

Comment: **can** and **will** are different words. a switch _can_ drop in hardware **if configured to do so**.  The 2960S will not by default, nor will a 2950, btw.  However, I totally agree src==dst should be dropped immediately; it's a rare enough event to not be coded into the hardware.

Comment: @RickyBeam, I think I now understand the point that you are objecting.  In my mind, the comments should be taken within the context of the question or answer on which it is made.  The **will** in my comment is based within the context of the previously provided answer, not default behavior.  If I could edit comments, then you would want an edit for clarity to say something like, "... but when when configured this way, most enterprise switches **will** drop the frames in hardware, there ..."  Correct?  I also am still confused where the 2960S came into the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

If this traffic is indeed 60% of traffic, then I would start with looking at the interfaces for higher volume of input. I would then have a list of suspects. At that point I would mac acl a port at a time looking for when the traffic disappears. Then I know the source port of the traffic and then debug that 'thing'.